# $http.post error code with 501

Tags: javascript, angularjs, xmlhttprequest, ionic-framework

post method in my ionic application as mentioned below

```
.factory('userProdDetails', function ($http) {

    return {
      getProdDetails: function () {
        return $http.post('http://192.xxx.x.2x4/filter_app.cgi', { "act": "Del", "oid": 1 }).then(function (response) {

          alert(JSON.stringify(response));

          return response;
        }, function (error) {

          console.log(error);

        });
      }
    }
  })
```

I am getting the following error in the console:

**OPTIONS http://xxx.xxx.x.25x/filter_app.cgi (anonymous function)
 XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://xxx.xxx.x.25x/filter_app.cgi.
 Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 501**

summary of the error object:

Object {data: null, status: 0, config: Object, statusText: ""}

Can you help me what are the reasons for this error,Am i missing anything?

Comment: The browser made a preflight OPTIONS request. The server responded with "?@£$%>£$?^£$>?!". You need to deal with this on your server, not your client.

Comment: @Quentin what is the meaning of preflight options request?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests